# How do I convert JSON data to an HTML table?

Tags: python, html, json

I am trying to display JSON data(I received from S3 bucket) into a HTML table like structure but I am unable to figure out a way to do that.

```
import boto3
import json
import click
import requests

boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='rli-dev', region_name='us-west-2')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3') 
content_object = s3.Object('bsdev-data-validation', 'awsnightlyendtoend_bsdev_2018-10-24T11:53:45Z/validate_adwactivityfact/job-details.json') 
file_content = content_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8-sig')
json_content = json.loads(file_content) 
print(json_content)
```

I am expecting the JSON data that I have it in "json_content" into a HTML(table) like structure

Comment: You could loop through the data, find the longest element, then add spaces/tabs to each other element to make it of equal length, then print each element with x tabs/spaces required and separate cells with | and _'s between lines.

Comment: can you help me with the snippet please? I am unclear at couple of places

Answer (score 2):

**Use json2html package:**

> $ pip install json2html

```
import boto3
import json
import click
import requests
from json2html import *

boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='rli-dev', region_name='us-west-2')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3') 
content_object = s3.Object('bsdev-data-validation', 'awsnightlyendtoend_bsdev_2018- 
10-24T11:53:45Z/validate_adwactivityfact/job-details.json') 
file_content = content_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8-sig')
json_content = json.loads(file_content)
print(json_content)

#Modify this to fit your need
input = {
    "name": "json2html",
    "description": "Converts JSON to HTML tabular representation"
}
test = json2html.convert(json = input)
print(test)
```

**Output of print(test) is:**

```html
<table border="1"><tr><th>name</th><td>json2html</td></tr><tr><th>description</th><td>Converts JSON to HTML tabular representation</td></tr></table>
```

**You can even do lists of JSON statements:**

```
from json2html import *

input = [{
        "name": "John Doe",
        "description": "Generic Man",
        "some data": "['brown hair', '5.10, 'accountant']"
}, {
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "description": "Generic woman",
        "some data": "['brown hair', '5.5, 'hair dresser']"
}]
test = json2html.convert(json = input)
print(test)
```

**Output of list-JSON:**

```html
<table border="1"><thead><tr><th>name</th><th>description</th><th>some data</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>John Doe</td><td>Generic
Man</td><td>[&#x27;brown hair&#x27;, &#x27;5.10, &#x27;accountant&#x27;]</td></tr><tr><td>Jane Doe</td><td>Generic woman</td><td>[&#x27;brown hair&#x27;, &#x27;5.5, &#x27;hair dresser&#x27;]</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: @Utkarsh let me know if this works.  I hope I understood your question correctly.